# Kitchen aerator doesn't want to screw tightly into place

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to replace my kitchen faucet's aerator, but as I'm tightening it, it'll reach a point where it sort of "pops" and becomes loose, allowing me to tighten it again. I'm not sure if that's a bad sign.

Anyway, I thought it might be due to all the grime that's built up on the faucet threads, so I took a toothbrush and some oil  and scrubbed it down pretty well.

Unfortunately, that didn't work. Taking the O-Ring out does allow me to tighten it completely, but that has a side-effect of causing the water pressure to be absolutely ridiculous.

So now I'm debating on getting some plumber's tape, or possibly running down to the hardware store to get a part or something to try and fix this.
[image]
[image]

Edit 03/31/2019: [image: Spigot threads]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Pictures of the aerator and that O-ring would be helpful.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Sure, [here you go.](https://imgur.com/a/NmqaqAi)

Comment: Are you trying to use the aerator in the picture? If so, which thread are you using, the inside (female) or outside (male) thread on the aerator? Did you try removing the black rubber gasket *but leaving the white plastic restrictor in*?

Comment: Note- that aerator is actually a combination device that aerates the water stream and also serves as a quick-connect adapter for a portable dishwasher...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I'm using the inside (female) thread, and removing the gasket lets the aerator tighten fully, however the water pressure is then too great.

Additionally, the aerator I am replacing is functionally identical to this one, except I lost the gasket over a year ago.

And I have a portable dishwasher.

Comment: I don't understand why the water flow increases with removal of **just** the rubber gasket...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I don't either, but that's what happens.

Comment: try silicone tape to tighten the threads a bit, so at least the "right before it pops" state is a bit tighter.

Comment: Take a picture of the faucet threads without it installed?

Comment: @Dotes Okay, it's done.